# CPPCMS build error with libraries

Tags: c++, cppcms

Despite I have open ssl installed, it can't find where the library is. The openssl exists in my Ubuntu as default, it still can't find, so I download a new distribution and reinstall it to /usr/local/ssl . I install by the default cmake command:

```
cmake ..
```

As well as explicitly specify the path:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib ..
```

It keeps generating this error:

```
-- Looking for ICU libraries
-- ICU not found, disabling ICU localization backend
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PCRE_LIB
    linked by target "booster" in directory /home/hoangtu/Programs/cppcms-0.99.7/booster
    linked by target "booster-static" in directory /home/hoangtu/Programs/cppcms-0.99.7/booster
```

What does it mean? It should find the open ssl. ICU is installed as default in Ubuntu as well. Also, what's the last two lines about?

*EDIT*: Ok, I downloaded and installed ICU to my usr directory. ICU found now. Now the only error remains:

```
-- Looking for ICU libraries
-- ICU Found, building booster locale
GNU-TLS Gcrypt or OpenSSL librarys are not found, disabling AES encryption support
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PCRE_LIB
    linked by target "booster" in directory /home/hoangtu/Programs/cppcms-0.99.7/booster
    linked by target "booster-static" in directory /home/hoangtu/Programs/cppcms-0.99.7/booster
```

is the booster thingy. Openssl stills not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great,

I found the answer here: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_build_troubleshooting

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpcre3-dev libicu-dev libgcrypt11-dev zlib1g-dev cmake
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your own answer.  I was screwed.